# Advanced grouping of items in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an interesting problem. I have to assign an ID to a group of orders, based on whether they are packed in the same group of containers or not. One order may be in one or many containers, which means that not all containers in the group contain all the orders. For example, given these orders:

```
 ORDER1 is in container A and B
 ORDER2 is in container B and C
 ORDER3 is in container C and D
 ORDER4 is in container E
```

There should be two groups, the first containing ORDER1, ORDER2 and ORDER3, and the second containing only ORDER4. Notice that ORDER1 and ORDER3 do not share any containers.

I can think of a reasonably straightforward procedural algorithm for doing this grouping - getting the details right might be a bit painful though.

However, I like to have an SQL based solution if possible, but it's beyond my grasp. I am using Oracle 10.2 - I am guessing that some funky features might come in to play here.

Comment: Can you please show the definition of the table(s) involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, similar to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351662/sql-combine-multiple-identifiers-to-create-a-group-id-for-duplicate-records). You can build a query following the same approach:

```
SQL> WITH orders AS (
  2     SELECT 'ORDER1' ord, 'A' cont FROM dual
  3     UNION ALL SELECT 'ORDER1' , 'B' FROM dual
  4     UNION ALL SELECT 'ORDER2' , 'B' FROM dual
  5     UNION ALL SELECT 'ORDER2' , 'C' FROM dual
  6     UNION ALL SELECT 'ORDER3' , 'C' FROM dual
  7     UNION ALL SELECT 'ORDER3' , 'D' FROM dual
  8     UNION ALL SELECT 'ORDER4' , 'E' FROM dual
  9  )
 10  SELECT ord, MIN(grp) "group" /*, cont*/
 11    FROM (SELECT connect_by_root(ord) ord,
 12                 connect_by_root(cont) cont,
 13                 cont grp
 14             FROM orders
 15           CONNECT BY NOCYCLE(cont = PRIOR cont
 16                           OR ord = PRIOR ord))
 17  GROUP BY ord /*, cont*/
 18  ORDER BY ord, MIN(grp);

ORD    group
------ -----
ORDER1 A
ORDER2 A
ORDER3 A
ORDER4 E
```

#### Update

I tried to generate some more data to reproduce your performance problem. With only a thousand orders the query indeed doesn't return in a timely fashion.

I tried to tweak the query with the CONNECT BY and START WITH clause but didn't manage to improve performance. My next idea was to display the data in a more traditional hierarchical view:

```
SQL> SELECT o1.ord "order", o2.ord "is connected to"
  2    FROM orders o1
  3    JOIN orders o2 ON o1.cont = o2.cont
  4                  AND o1.ord < o2.ord;

order  is connected to
------ ---------------
ORDER1 ORDER2
ORDER2 ORDER3
```

This in turn is the base for the following query that did quite well on my test data set:

```
SQL> SELECT o.ord, nvl(MIN(connexions.grp), o.ord) grp
  2    FROM orders o
  3    LEFT JOIN (SELECT connect_by_root(ord1) grp, ord2
  4                      --, sys_connect_by_path(ord1, '->')
  5                 FROM (SELECT o1.ord ord1, o2.ord ord2
  6                          FROM orders o1
  7                          JOIN orders o2 ON o1.cont = o2.cont
  8                                        AND o1.ord < o2.ord)
  9               CONNECT BY PRIOR ord2 = ord1
 10                ORDER BY 1, 2) connexions ON o.ord = connexions.ord2
 11    GROUP BY o.ord
 12    order by 1,2;

ORD    GRP
------ ------
ORDER1 ORDER1
ORDER2 ORDER1
ORDER3 ORDER1
ORDER4 ORDER4
```

I used the following query to populate my data set (1200 rows):

```
CREATE TABLE orders AS
SELECT 'ORDER' || to_char(dbms_random.VALUE(0, 1000), 'fm000000') ord,
       to_char(dbms_random.VALUE(0, 800), 'fm000000') cont
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1200;
```

Comment: Thanks - that looks OK from a correct data point of view. When I tried it on a more representative sample (around 200 orders), it was very slow. When I removed the "group by" clause from this solution, I got 37 rows (from the seven rows in the data), and this grew (presumably some polynomial relationship) to a very large number. So the question is how to trim the middle query. Not sure how to go about it. It may well be that a procedural solution is the best way to go.

Comment: @greg: the inner query is a brute force query with no subtlety that will build for each row all the corresponding groups possible with that row. In your procedural approach you will probably not try every grouping possible, you can have something similar in the SQL with the START WITH clause and a "smarter" CONNECT BY clause.

Comment: You are right - I think I will stick with the procedural solution for now. It will be easier for the people who come after to understand anyway. I can't think of a suitable "starts with" clause unfortunately.

Comment: @greg: your remark piqued my curiosity. I managed to obtain reasonable performance on a larger data set by modifying the query. Still, with very large data sets (>1 million rows) even this query will be impractical.

Comment: That looks like a very interesting solution - I might give it a go (although I have finished the code for the original problem now). I'd give you another upvote if I could!